# Finding a constant and non constant power wire in a car

Tags: ignition, buick, aftermarket-upgrade, century

The car I have is a 2001 Buick century. I have a after market push to start kit. It came with a main unit and the diagram shows that a brown wire is for a constant power when the engine is on. And a white wire that needs a non constant power. the diagram says a non constant power when engine is started it's not hot

Comment: That's going to be hard to find. Usually, most wires are either constant power (power is on whether the *key* is in the on position or off position) and non-constant power where the power is off if the car is off. Can you double check to ensure what you put in your question is exactly what your instructions read? Also, what is the make/model of the aftermarket kit you are installing? This would help us tremendously in helping you.

Comment: This is the copy of what the company over the aftermarket push/start said : For Most Cars:
ON.1 --- Power Supply Wire: Keep power on when engine start; ON.2 --- Power Supply Wire: Keep power cut off when engine start.

Comment: It's Guarder 0s838c RFID push engine start

Comment: Sorry, I had to ask. I read some stuff online. They say the instructions are next to useless (something about a Chinese 3rd grader). Anyway, I hope someone can answer your question. This is a tough one.

Comment: A power wire that is NOT hot when the engine is on? Why would it need that?

Comment: @Andre  Can you review/edit your question and add any clarifications that you can?  As well, if you have a link to the instruction manual.  Please provide that as well.  If you've resolved the issue, please post an answer and give yourself credit for it  :-)   I'm interested in what this not HOT lead is.  Very odd.

Comment: I found http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/61lqElpAQPL._SY450_.jpg but it's next to impossible to read.

Answer (score 1):

The only place where I'd expect such a wire is the one between the ignition lock and the starter relay (i.e. the one that tells the starter to crank).
Do they expect you to splice your starter button into this lead?